# Attach shipping courier selection at drupal cart commerce line item

Tags: commerce

Anyone have Idea how to attach shipping courier selection at drupal commerce cart? As seen at capture bellow, I want to attach shipping courier selection at cart, so I can pick shipping courier for each order line item. Anyone have Idea?

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OMoDWmIZcyo/VFkLxBQGcWI/AAAAAAAACtc/lCidjfXgeSI/w1043-h396-no/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 0):

I think [Commerce Delivery](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_delivery) module solved your problem.

Or you need to add Shipping plugin.

Please check this two links. I think this may help you.

[Link 1](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/calculating-flat-rate-based-customer%E2%80%99s-shipping-address)

[Link 2](http://www.baggagefreight.com.au/ecommerce-integration/drupal/)